# VBS script (VBScript) errors 800A0035 and/or 800A004C only on the first execution of the script

Tags: vbscript, path, runtime-error, wsh

I am pretty new to all this VBS stuff because basically all I need to do is to make one simple VBS script, which I have possibly written, however, my problem is that it gives me `800A0035` or `800A004C` error when I execute it for the first time on a particular PC, as soon as I execute it for the second time, it runs just OK and does what it is supposed to do. Incidentally, on my own computer it works OK even on the first execution.
I know that the errors have something to do with the wrong paths but I have checked my script several times and I am 100% positive that they are correct.

Here is the script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.MoveFile "rar.bat" , "rarp.bat"
'HideBat.vbs
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "rarp.bat", 0, True
```

What the script is supposed to do is to rename the `rar.bat` file to `rarp.bat` and run that batch file (`rarp.bat`) without popping up the command prompt. What the batch file does is not relevant, I guess, but anyway, it just runs *WinRAR*.

The `rar.bat` file and the VBS script are in the same folder, that's why I have used relative paths in the script. I cannot use absolute paths because I need to run the script on several computers.

I have read somewhere on the internet that by default VBS script first looks for the files in `C:\Windows\System32` when relative paths are used. I have even tried using absolute paths in the script but it didn't work either. Here is how I need them to look like: `%systemdrive%\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\rar.bat` but this simply didn't work in the VBS script.

I really think that what I need is really a simple script but apparently it's pretty hard to get it working properly. I will be very grateful to those who help me.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Regards.

Comment: For the *8nnnnnnn* errors, try unregistering then re-registering these files: `CSCRIPT.EXE, JSCRIPT.DLL, MSSCRIPT.OCX, SCRIPTLE.DLL, VBSCRIPT.DLL, WSCRIPT.EXE, WSHOM.OCX`

Comment: well, thanks for your advice but I am a total beginner in VBS scripts. Could you please tell me how to unregister and reregister those files please?

Comment: Use `regsvr32 /u {the filename}` to unregister and `regsvr32 {filename}` to register. Run from command prompt and from Windows' `SYSTEM32` directory.

Comment: ok I understand what you mean but I need to run the VBS script first, without running anything else before. Is it anyhow possible to register and unregister those files via VBS script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That DLL un/registering are not supposed to be run manually as the error is probably caused by a corrupted Windows registry that affect *Windows Scripting* feature. It should only be run once either from a batch file or typed manually via command prompt and not from within a VBScript/JScript.

Comment: I reckon that it is not due to a corrupted Windows registry because my problem occurs on every other computer but mine. I have tried running it on at least nine different computers. Do you have any other suggestions, please? How about implementing "GetParentFolder" in the VBS script? Could it be of any help in telling the script that the "far.bat" is in the same folder as the VBS script itself?

Answer (score 1):

The only way your script - at least the part published - can give an error is by not finding the source file for renaming, you should have added full script and error message to be sure.
I suppose this is caused by a security setting on your pc that are more forgiving than on the rest of the pc's, eg UAC ? On the other pc's, try to put the files in a map like c:\test and then run it again after checking that the file rar.bat does exist in the same map. Do you have the same credentials (admin) on the other pc's ?
If you just want to run the bat file hidden, why the renaming ?

how do you download the bat ? and how then is invoked the script ? could be a timing issue that the second time is no longer a problem. In that case check in your script if the file is allready there and do a sleep in a loop while it doesn't

If you want to use the absolute path you could try this

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshSysEnv = WshShell.Environment("PROCESS")
path = WshSysEnv("USERPROFILE") & "\appdata\roaming\rar.bat"
wscript.echo path
objFSO.MoveFile path , "rarp.bat"
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "rarp.bat", 1, True
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the part I published is the entire script. Here is the picture of the error: "http://i.imgur.com/U63tF.png" I don't think it is caused by security settings of the other PCs because I have tried it on several computers, XP, VISTA and Win7, with limited accounts as well as administrator accounts. It didn't work, it behave in the same fashion on each computer. It didn't work on the first execution (it gives the error) BUT it works perfectly on the second execution. This is what I cannot comprehend! I also followed your advice and put files in C:\ to no avail.

Comment: I checked that "rar.bat" exists in the same folder as the script. Even my colleagues helped me. Why does that script works fine when run for the second time? Shouldn't I somehow specify the paths using "GetParentFolder" (have no idea how to)? As I stated before, I am 100% sure that the files are in the same folder at the same time. Any other ideas? I still think that there must be something that has anything to do with the fact that it runs fine on the second execution. By the way, the VBS script is downloaded to those PCs, hence the renaming.

Comment: added some advise to my answer based on the new info

Comment: thanks, I give up on trying to execute the bat file using the realtive path. Is there a way to use absolute path using environment variables in the VBS script? Something like: objFSO.MoveFile "%systemdrive%\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\rar" , "%systemdrive%\users\%username%\appdata\roaming\rarp.bat" I know that this code doesn't work in the VBS script, it works only in Windows command line but is there any way to use the above mentione environment variables in the VBS script? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: sure, again edited my answer, but if it is a timing issue it won't help